# How can I reduce the pressure and flow to only part of an irrigation system?

Tags: tools, irrigation, water, hoses

I'm designing a more permanent tree irrigation system for my property to replace the makeshift only I currently have that uses garden hoses. To water the trees, I've settled on non-pressurized lines that are open at the ends (to eliminate the problem of clogging, as we have extremely hard water). To ensure that the flow isn't too high, I need a way to reduce the flow so it just dribbles out. To do this right now, I just open my hose bib spigot a tiny bit so the flow is extremely low, and it works fine. However, this means I can't run the sprinkler at the same time.

For the system I'm designing, I want to preserve the high pressure high flow at the hose bib so I can run the sprinkler (high flow, high pressure) at the same time as the dribbly tree irrigation part (low flow, low pressure). I have not had much luck finding a product or method to accomplish this. How can I reduce the flow and pressure for only one of the lines? I almost feel like what I want to do is add another hose bib, or a shut-off valve that uses a globe valve instead of a ball valve. I want to be able to throttle the flow, basically.

Comment: Would something like [this](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61znIBZPRML._SY355_.jpg) work, turned partly, but not entirely off? They come as a y also...

Comment: I suspect the ball would fully open over time due to water pressure.

Comment: What is your pressure?

Comment: The water pressure is 70 PSI.

Comment: That is normal/highish, not unusual. I don't think it will be an issue, they work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a shut-off ball valve (as opposed to a butterfly) such as the one pictured, turned to the required gpm.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A twin faucet outlet simplifies things. If you really need to irrigate both trees and sprinkler at same time  just add a metafim reducer to the line supplying the trees.ideally a twin faucet with two timers separating irrigation times giving you full pressure for the sprinkling application. And as I mentioned metafim have a range of inline pressure reducers to solve your problem.now this is a general response to a very  general question. How many trees etc. we use an array of faucets mounted on a manifold with each own timing system to irrigate large sea-side properties  here in Croatia. I like the twin faucets just for this reason.it allows me to reduce a line and still have full mains pressure on the other outlet.